# Tailwind CSS and Angular Universal FOUC

Tags: tailwind-css

I have Tailwind set up and it works great on the pages I've migrated. But it's introduced a flash-of-unstyled-content problem because the stylesheet is loaded after the HTML, instead of inside of the HTML file. It's a HUGE drag on the PageSpeed CLS score.

Others have had similar issues, and a resolution exists in some other cases. For example, how does one do something like this for Angular Universal +13:

https://shubhamverma.me/blog/server-side-rendering-of-tailwind-css-styles-in-next-js